# What is an effective way for other objects to get a pointer to a singleton?

Tags: java, oop

What is an effective way for other objects to get a pointer to a singleton?  In my case I have a `Data` object, created at application init time, which many objects need to touch.  It is `final` and supposed to be around for the whole application lifecycle.  Data sharing is done through an `interface` (fields are not exposed).

This is actually two questions in one:

1. How should objects get a reference
   to `Data`?
2. Should they get it once
       and store it, or just get it every
       time they need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - An accessor method inside your Data class definition should do the trick.

```
public class Data
{
  private static Data myData = null;

  private Data() // Private constructor for singletons
  {
     // ...
  }

  public static Data getInstance()
  {
     if(myData == null)
         myData = new Data();

     return myData;
  }
}
```

2 - I believe it would be stored as a reference in Java and not a copy of the object, so I don't think it would matter much.  Whichever you prefer while coding.

Comment: It is recommended to name the accessor method 'getInstance'. It helps to make more obvious the fact that it's a singleton class.

Comment: @Marcelo yes, you're absolutely right.  That was an oversight on my part.  Edited my answer.

Comment: need to get rid of `final` in `myData` declaration

Comment: Here is a further improvement which avoids potential multithreading problems: `private static final Data myData = new Data()` and then `getInstance()` becomes just `return myData`.  Apparently if threads are not synchronized properly, one thread may not see that `myData` is no longer null.

Answer (score 1):

I would request you to go through ITEM#1 from [EFFECTIVE JAVA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) to know all about of singleton.

You would be able to know all in and out.

Comment: ... and once you read item #1... read all of them! All the content in that book is just fabulous.

Comment: The book has an example similar to rchanley's and also a very cool note at the end:  the best way to do this is with an `enum`! As in, `[public] enum Data { INSTANCE; }`.  Since enums can have methods, fields, and even implement interfaces, you can still do everything and access with `Data.INSTANCE.foo()` etc.  If the `enum` is `public` you can access from anywhere.